# Present participle usage

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I can not figure out how 'deciding' is being used here?

> The fame election management skill of the party  came under stress **with the party deciding** to replace candidate Mr. X with Mr.Y as the candidate for contesting the election.

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/present-participle/ and scroll down to the bottom "The present participle to explain a reason". The decision is the reason why the party was under stress.

By the way, I think it should read "The *famed* (famous) election management skill..."

Comment: Why with is used here?

Comment: One of the definitions of _with_ is _in relation to, because of_ .